# Transfer time from JFK Terminal 4 to Terminal 2?

Tags: jfk, accessibility

Virgin has booked a ticket for my wife (who requires disabled assistance) and myself via New York JFK, with a transfer from Terminal 4 to Terminal 2. The time between our arrival and departure is 43 minutes.

We are travelling on one ticket. Is this a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: Is this international-to-domestic or domestic-to-international?

Answer (score 4):

> Is this a reasonable time?

If they booked it as a single ticket, they are sure enough that you will make it

> (requiring disabled assist )

Usually, if you require assistance, you will get to skip most queues, for example at immigration, this is not always, though.

It is likely that you will have a special arrangement, as customs in JFK can take a **lot** of time depending on the day and time and whether you are a US Citizen/LPR (you can have a rough estimate at [AWT](https://awt.cbp.gov/))

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound reasonable to me, even if you're able to skip all the queues.

The walk from T4 to the AirTrain stop is at least 15 minutes.

The wait for the AirTrain could be zero if you'te lucky, but could be as long as 10 minutes.

I think, you are very likely not to make it.